# java mac address different than iwconfig

Tags: java

I have function for read MAC address in java:

> ```
>     for(Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enm = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); enm.hasMoreElements();){
>         NetworkInterface network = (NetworkInterface) enm.nextElement();
>           if(null != network.getHardwareAddress()){
>               System.out.print(network.getDisplayName());
>               byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
>               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(18);
>               for (byte b : mac) {
>                   if (sb.length() > 0)
>                       sb.append(':');
>                   sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
>               }                  
>
>               System.out.print(sb.toString());
>               return null; 
>           }
>        }
> ```

This result:
wlan0: 00:25:d3:9c:ad:7a
But when I do: iwconfig, I reveive: 00:0D:F3:0D:DD:DC for wlan0

Question, why ?

EDIT:
I am sorry for question,
When I run ifconfig (not iwconfig) it responds:

> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:d3:9c:ad:7a
>             inet addr:192.168.50.100  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::225:d3ff:fe9c:ad7a/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:2417546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:1608679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:3099222889 (3.0 GB)  TX bytes:183978636 (183.9 MB)

So it's okay, thank you anyway.

Comment: One is for an [AzureWave based product](http://aruljohn.com/mac.pl?mac=0025d3), one is for an [Asmax based product](http://aruljohn.com/mac.pl?mac=000df3), so seemingly two different wireless cards. Are you sure that you're running iwconfig on the same machine as you're executing the Java program?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is one machine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code:

```
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enm = NetworkInterface
            .getNetworkInterfaces(); enm.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface network = (NetworkInterface) enm.nextElement();
        if (null != network.getHardwareAddress()) {
            System.out.print(network.getDisplayName() + " is ");
            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(18);
            for (byte b : mac) {
                if (sb.length() > 0)
                    sb.append(':');
                sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
```

This will print out the names/mac addresses of all the network interfaces, your old code just did the first one. See if any of these mac addresses match the one being given by iwconfig